# How to catch the event when a page is about to replaced in a frame

Tags: javascript, html, frame

Objective: To be able to capture just before a page in a frame

Below are a stripped down versions of what I have been working on. If trap just trap onload event using javascript the event is captured when the page is loaded when I add a handler for onunload it also executed when the page is loaded
.This seems to work fine when the page in question is not in a frame, but when it is frame I get this behavior. Any help you might be able to give would be appreciated.

index.htm -----

```
<HTML>

 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>New Hampshire</TITLE>

 </HEAD>


 <!-- You may make other changes, but do not change the names  -->
 <!-- of the frames (treeframe and basefrm).                   -->

 <FRAMESET cols="220,*" onResize="if (navigator.family == 'nn4') window.location.reload()"> 
  <FRAME src="./tree.htm" name="treeframe"> 
  <FRAME  src="./test.htm"  name="mainframe"> 
 </FRAMESET> 

</HTML>
```

tree.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
    <title>Tree</title>
</head>


</body>

<p><a target="mainframe" href="test.htm">test.htm</a></p>
<p><a target="mainframe" href="test2.htm">test2.htm</a></p>
<p><a target="mainframe" href="test3.htm">test3.htm</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</html>
```

test.htm, test2.htm, test3.htm -- basically the same file just the text in teh body is different to reflect the different file/

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
</head>
<script>
    window.onload=alert('Page is loaded')
    window.onresize=alert('Page is unloaded')
</script>
<body>
  <p>Page 1,</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `capture just before a page in a frame` mean?  I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Don't use frames at all...

Comment: Let try to explain it in a scenario:

Comment: Sorry, something happened to what I wrote....... ( You have a page displayed in a frame 2) You click on a link to display another page in a frame. The question that I have is there an event that I can capture so that I know that page is changing in the frame? I know that the javascript on load method capture when the page is loaded.

Comment: Tried with iframes same result ......